# EF Core passing configuration manager connection string is throwing null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core in an ASP.NET webforms application.

This is the connection string that I am referencing:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

`DbContext` configuration:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
}
```

When I update the database, it is throwing a null reference error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

call stack :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SolutionName.Repositories.DataContext.get__connectionString() in C:\SolutionName\Repositories\DataContext.cs:line 13
   at SolutionName.Repositories.DataContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\SolutionName\Repositories\DataContext.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: webforms , this was a mistake tag

Comment: And then why are you using EF **Core** with a webforms app ??

Comment: that's a long story, however, everything is working except for the issue that i posted

Comment: @SafiHabhab - can you post the call stack related to the NullReferenceException you are receiving?

Comment: ok i posted the stack

Comment: Take the normal debugging steps: put `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataContextConnString"].ConnectionString` into a variable and check its value in the debugger.

Comment: i did it returned the wanted string